# A question about Milvus distance calculation

Tags: distance, milvus

I have a question about distance calculation in Milvus. In Milvus, I use the L2 distance calculation to query a vector for top1 and Milvus returns a distance of 9.340524. whereas the distance I get between the query vector and the return using the L2 formula is 2.156227.
Why is the formula for distance calculated differently from the result returned by Milvus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The L2 distance is returned by FAISS, it is a square value.  For example, vector1=[1,2], vector2=[0, 4], the returned L2 distance is 5.

You got L2 distance 9.340524, but it is not equal to 2.156227*2.156227, I think there must be some mistakes. You can do the steps to verify:

1. create a new collection
2. insert the vector that you got from the previous query(the top1 vector)
3. query again